# Why background agent loads redundant assemblies?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing an app for Windows Phone. This app uses background agent (scheduled task) for updating information on tiles pinned to the start screen.

I have 4 projects which produce 4 assemblies:

- MyApp - Main project with UI logic
- MyApp.Core - Main logic of the app
- MyApp.Core.Agent - Stripped-down version of MyApp.Core for the background agent
- MyApp.Agent - Background agent

This is a part of agent's log which contains list of assemblies loaded by the agent:

```
Zlib, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
MyApp.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
MyApp.Core.Agent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
MyApp.Agent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC
Microsoft.Phone.Interop, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24EEC0D8C86CDA1E
Microsoft.Phone, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24EEC0D8C86CDA1E
System.Core, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC
System.Xml, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC
System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7CEC85D7BEA7798E
System, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC
System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7CEC85D7BEA7798E
System.Windows.RuntimeHost, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7CEC85D7BEA7798E
mscorlib, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC
```

MyApp.Agent has reference only on MyApp.Core.Agent, which has no references on other projects. But as you can see MyApp and MyApp.Core are also loaded when the background agent starts. Why that happens? I can't understand. MyApp and MyApp.Core assemblies do nothing but reduce valuable memory space.

Comment: Hi Alex, it seems unlikely that anyone would be able to answer this question outside of Microsoft. I could provide speculation, but that would not be useful. Is the loading of these assemblies causing you any problems?

Comment: @GaryJohnson I was forced to abandon the use of background agent in WP7-version of my app (on WP8 all is ok). Memory consumption exceeded 6Mb limit. And this exceeding was not big (about 0.5-1Mb). So I thought that disabling of loading redundant assemblies could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that this happens is to enable drawing from the Background Agent (essentially this dll gets loaded in since it has all the right components to support a Visual Tree). This isn't necessarily a great reason since not all agents render in the background but the hit for those who don't is extremely small since the framework only reads a small amount of the dll at startup.